# Laravel eloquent query with collection optimization

Tags: laravel, optimization, eloquent, collections

I have the following queries in my controller to show some statistics about orders paid, and unpaid and the respective amounts (totals), by year. Yet, I feel that the queries I'm using may be optimized but I can't figure out a better way to do it. Here's what I have:

```
public function index(Order $order)
{
    $orders = Order::all()->groupBy(function ($order) {
        return $order->created_at->format('Y');
    })->map(function ($year) {
        return $year->sum('total');
    });
    
    $unpaid_orders = Order::all()->where('payment_confirmed', 0)->groupBy(function ($order) {
        return $order->created_at->format('Y');
    })->map(function ($year) {
        return $year->sum('total');
    });
    
    $paid_orders = Order::all()->where('payment_confirmed', 1)->groupBy(function ($order) {
        
        return $order->payment_confirmed == false ? $order->year : $order->created_at->format('Y');
    })->map(function ($year) {
        return $year->sum('total');
    });
    
    return view('orders.index', compact('orders', 'unpaid_orders', 'paid_orders'));
}
```

Above I'm querying the Order model three times which it seems that could be optimized.

Comment: why do you call `::all()` and then the `where()` instead of `Order::where()`. Doesn't `all()` fetch everything and then filter instead of immediately filtering?

Comment: Do once `$orders = Order::all();` and use `$orders` variable to filter/modify instead of repeating `Order::all()` query for three of them.

Comment: You can also fetch neccessary columns from the database to save memory for better performance like `$orders = Order::select(['id', 'payment_confirmed', 'total', 'created_at'])->get();`

Comment: Yes, selecting only the necessary columns is a way to reduce memory, yet my problem is with querying the order model three times. I presume there's a way to use the collection method to get the three variables `$orders`, `$unpaid_orders`, and `$paid_orders` with only calling once the `Order::class` model.

Comment: @js-tech Still trying to figure out how to get the data with only on query for the three variables.

Comment: @McRui have in mind that, if you still have a lot of models, you should then have 3 queries and tell each query exactly what you want, so you let the database handle the filtering, as the database will be way more faster than PHP mapping it with a Collection, but in that case, you need to share more info, like how many items are being returned, how much memory is being used after getting the results, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `$collection = Order::all();` once and use `$collection` wherever you need it.

```
public function index(Order $order)
{
    $collection = Order::all();

    // OR

    $collection = Order::select(['id', 'payment_confirmed', 'total', 'year', 'created_at'])->get();

    $orders = $collection->groupBy(fn ($order) => $order->created_at->format('Y'))
        ->map(fn ($order) => $order->sum('total'));

    $unpaid_orders = $collection->where('payment_confirmed', 0)
        ->groupBy(fn ($order) => $order->created_at->format('Y'))
        ->map(fn ($order) => $order->sum('total'));

    $paid_orders = $collection->where('payment_confirmed', 1)
        ->groupBy(
            fn ($order) => $order->payment_confirmed == false
                ? $order->year
                : $order->created_at->format('Y')
        )
        ->map(fn ($order) => $order->sum('total'));

    return view('orders.index', compact('orders', 'unpaid_orders', 'paid_orders'));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've tested and it works. And with your solution, I only call the Order model one time, and this is was I was doing wrong – calling it three times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the query in the provided code using scopes, you can define scopes in your Order model. Scopes allow you to encapsulate reusable query logic, making it easier to optimize and maintain your code. Here's an optimized version of the code using **scopes**:

First, let's define the scopes in your **Order** model:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function scopeUnpaid($query)
    {
        return $query->where('payment_confirmed', 0);
    }

    public function scopePaid($query)
    {
        return $query->where('payment_confirmed', 1);
    }

    public function scopeGroupByYear($query)
    {
        return $query->groupBy(function ($order) {
            return $order->created_at->format('Y');
        });
    }
}
```

Now, let's modify the index method to utilize these scopes:

```
public function index(Order $order)
{
    $orders = Order::groupByYear()->get()->map(function ($year) {
        return $year->sum('total');
    });

    $unpaid_orders = Order::unpaid()->groupByYear()->get()->map(function ($year) {
        return $year->sum('total');
    });

    $paid_orders = Order::paid()->groupByYear()->get()->map(function ($year) {
        return $year->sum('total');
    });

    return view('orders.index', compact('orders', 'unpaid_orders', 'paid_orders'));
}
```

By using scopes, we can chain the necessary conditions and group by logic directly on the Order model, resulting in cleaner and more optimized code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Nevertheless, it uses the same three queries to the Order model. The first solution that I accepted is the most efficient.